# python gives array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I have coded mini_batch creator for miniBatchGradientDescent

The code is here:

```
# function to create a list containing mini-batches 
def create_mini_batches(X,y, batch_size): 
    print(X.shape, y.shape) # gives (280, 34) (280,)
    splitData=[]
    splitDataResults=[]
    batchCount=X.shape[0] // batch_size #using floor division for getting indexes integer form 
    for i in range(batchCount):
            splitData.append(X[(i) * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size, :])
            splitDataResults.append(y[(i) * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size, :]) # GIVES ERROR
    splitData=np.asarray(splitData)
    splitDataResults=np.asarray(splitDataResults)
    return splitData, splitDataResults, batchCount
```

the error says:

```
splitDataResults.append(y[(i) * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size, :])
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I am sure that the shape is correct but it gives me an error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try reshaping y:

```
print(X.shape, y.shape) # gives (280, 34) (280,)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

this should fix your problem, since y will become 2 dimentional

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That solved my problem. Can you explain why this solved?

Comment: y shape was (280,) this is a 1D NumPy array, so you can't really use [ i , j ] to index as you did in the line that raised the exception, you tried to index into two dimension of a 1D array.
after doing the reshape, it becomes (280, 1) so it is a 2D array and your indexing works as expected